# UISegmentedCotrol Hidden

Tags: iphone, ios, visibility, uisegmentedcontrol

I created a `UISegmentedControl` through the following snippet.

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", nil];
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(105, 270, 140, 30);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(selectWeek:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

When I press the button to turn `UISegmentedCotrol`, it doesn't work. What could be wrong?
I'm doing `segmentedControl.hidden = YES;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

**change it to**

```
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

and make sure `segmentedControl.hidden=NO`; when you add it to subview;

Comment: I need to navigationController do this, but I add to self.view and this not work

Comment: NSLog(@" %@",segmentedControl); after you add it in subview and check if the log shows the object or nil...

Comment: <UISegmentedControl: 0x4e3ef90; frame = (105 27; 140 30); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4e3f000>>
here hidden=YES but I see segmentedCotrol in my screen

Comment: so do you have any code to hide it in your project.. and also what exact do you want to achieve.your code is correct.. what problem are you getting..i can't really comment about the hidden = YES since that is object info ..and i just know that object exists from this NSlog otherwise it would have logged null..so can you post the method where you make the segment on.??

Comment: yes...maybe..someone else might do it too..just post any code related to this UISegment ..that way it is easier to know what you are doing.. if you post a particular section ..we start finding error in that only ..even if the error is somewhere else..waste of time for both of us.

Comment: file in project "TimetableViewController.h"
here  function create segmentbutton "-(void) setupSegmentedButton"
and function "-(void) addNew " which must hidden

Comment: i can't run it.. index.html missing.. you have Skype ?